Why all my windows refresh and stutter every half hour, at exactly 00 and 30 minutes?
I'm using Windows 10 Professional on a desktop PC. At exactly 0 and 30 minutes of each hour the whole system stutters and lags for a moment. I.e. every half hour. Looks like this: each window gets a focus briefly, gets redrawn (blinks white), and after a few seconds it's all back to normal. If I type while it's happening, keystrokes are lost.
What might be the cause? It happens even if I just open a Notepad and do nothing.
I've also tried adjusting the clock to 59 or 29 minutes; sometimes the same strange things happens at the next "fake" 0/30 minutes, sometimes it does not.

A Reddit post gave me an idea that worked in my case: it was due to desktop's background (wallpaper) being a "Slideshow" instead of a static picture.

Right click on the desktop.
Choose "Personalize" to open the Settings app.
Click under the "Background" label and choose any option other than "Slideshow":


I'm not sure whether there is anything else specific to my setup that caused the issue.
There might be other explanations for these symptoms as well.

When you select a slideshow, the transition itself is what causes lag. You can (forgot how) set it to instantly change image without transition (I believe it is in power management) and the lag will be gone then too.
